# Vega-lite: Cannot resolve dual y-axis on hconcat graph

Tags: vega-lite, vegas-viz

I currently have 2 graphs which are horizontally concatenated and I can select variables on the first graph and get more information on them displayed on the second. I am trying to resolve the y-axis on the second graph so that I have 2 y-axis with different units, and have figured out how to separate the axis on the left and right side, but the units are identical. This is not very useful and **I would like to know how to have independent scales on both**. From the documentation it seems as though using the resolve function should do the trick, but all it does is separates the axis.

Here is my code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "data/Per_Species_Per_Location/Fisher_location137.csv"
  },
  "spacing": 15,
  "hconcat": [{"layer":
    [{   "encoding": {
        "color": {
            "title": "Total (PPA)",
            "field": "Total",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "scale": {"range": ["#FFCC66", "#09bc8a", "#023057"]}
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Variable",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"labelAngle": -45, "title": "Element",
        "grid": false}
        },
        "y": {
          "title": "Total (PPA)",
          "field": "Total",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "fillOpacity": {
      "condition": {"selection": "select", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.25
    },
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Variable", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Total", "type": "quantitative"},
    ]
      },
      "width": 750,
      "height": 400,
      "selection": {"select": {"encodings": ["x"], "type": "multi"}},
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "cursor": "pointer"},
    }]},
    {"layer":[
      {"width": 150,
      "height": 400,
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "click",
            "field": "Sex",
            "type": "nominal",
            "scale": {"range": ["#7a003c", "#FFCC66", "#5b6770"]}
          },
          "value": "lightgray"
        },
        "y": {"field": "Sex Value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean", "axis": {"orient": "left"}},
        "x": {"title": "Sex", "field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Sex Value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean"},
      {"field": "Count", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "sum"}
    ]
      },
      "selection": {"click": {"encodings": ["color"], "type": "multi"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "select"}}]},
      {"mark": "rule",
      "encoding":{
        "y": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": "Reference",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "axis": {"orient": "right"}
      },
      "color": {"value": "black"},
      "size": {"value": 3}
      },
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "select"}}]}
    ]}], "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
}
```

Here is a picture of how the graph looks currently:

[image: Vega-lite graph]

As you can see, the mean of the sex value and mean of the reference have identical axis scales, and I want them to be different, so that the bars can be easily seen.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you set independent scales for dual y-axis is using `"resolve"` in the layer chart. Here is a minimal example that shows that it works in an hconcat ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAyhgB7wgBiGAtqhiADQhHEAEAaqpvAMyMBKGAGYYAThgB2AYzpwALACYAvvUIkyAWVoMmJdpxnz+Q0ROnxZABmWrScEAFVxAa3EB7AO7jtzPehkBGI2ExKRlZAFZFAF1lEAALSVcpaDxQGhEnMgAHVwBLcShtU1cwfIBzeFBbUEFcjBQwMh8OP20oAE8smRAARzQIAtyYKFzEOlj2ypBa+sa7AWDTOkYOrrI+gZHh0fHFaxAUCHbRVJB0zLsAIwgRIqkS8qnqkFXutyp81G0Zhqa1Camr3W-UG2zG2ggZTKYjK0G6VAwA2+dV+dma+hAe325zIIjQKGWIGKpXEFQQIEm5KBdg2oOgOwhUJhcLICKRjB+cxACxMoUxeyijDEWFcKHB5Kwki05MpIHyYAwXXECoK-OiiiAA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Sex": "Female", "Sex Value": 3, "Reference": 42},
      {"Sex": "Male", "Sex Value": 2, "Reference": 40},
      {"Sex": "Unknown", "Sex Value": 1, "Reference": 45}
    ]
  },
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Sex Value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Reference", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Sex"},
            "y": {
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean",
              "field": "Sex Value"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": "rule",
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "mean",
              "field": "Reference"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

I believe the reason it's not working in your case is that you put the resolve in the `hconcat` rather than putting the resolve in the `layer`. In other words, instead of the last line of your specification being:

```json
   ]}], "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
```

you should use:

```json
   ], "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}}]
```